# John Fauvel video on de Prony's Tables du cadastre

Tags: ho.history-overview

Ivor Grattan-Guinness in his contribution to {\it The History of Mathematical Tables} titled 
"The Computation Factory: de Prony's project for making tables in the 1790s" references a video made by John Fauvel for the Open University.  There a couple of stills from the video showing Fauvel sitting in front of the copy of de Prony's tables at the Institute.

Does anyone know if this video is still in existence and if so how it might be obtained?

Thanks for any insight.

Cheers, Scott

Answer (score 1):

You might look at

http://library.open.ac.uk/find/images/

especially the bottom of the page  "The Library holds a large collection of programmes co-produced by the Open University and the BBC on video, DVD and audio formats...."